# FileSystemWatcher does not work with path set to drive root if on same drive as application

Tags: c#, .net, path, filesystemwatcher

I'm using `FileSystemWatcher` to check for changes to `.exe` files anywhere on a drive.

```
FileSystemWatcher Watcher;

[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
public void Start() {
    Watcher = new FileSystemWatcher("C:") {
        NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes | NotifyFilters.CreationTime | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Size | NotifyFilters.Security,
        Filter = "*.exe",
        IncludeSubdirectories = true
    };
    Watcher.Created += OnChanged; //Among other events
    Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) {
    Debug.WriteLine(e.FullPath);
}
```

The issue is, if I have the watcher's path set to `C:` to check for files on the entire `C:` drive while also having my application being run anywhere on the `C:` drive (Eg. `C:\Users\Name\Desktop\App.exe`), the watcher doesn't fire any events.

If I instead set the path to `C:\Users` then the watcher will fire events - but this is of course limited to changes made to files under `C:\Users` which doesn't help if the file is in `Program Files` or such instead.

The same issue happens if I have the watcher checking the `D:` drive while my application is anywhere on the `D:` drive.

So it seems to not be possible to set the path to the root of the drive that the application is running on.  What could be causing this?

Comment: Can't reproduce. How are you testing this?

Comment: Doesn't fire any events at all?

Comment: Encounter a problem close than yours , i can't have any signal if i watch the root of a drive with the subfolder flag set to false. It works for subfolders but not at all with "e:\" by example.  Same will all drives letter on windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `@"C:\"` to the constructor instead of `"C:"`.

The path `C:` means "the current directory on the `C:` drive" whereas `C:\` means "the root directory on the `C:` drive."  You can see this for yourself by opening `Command Prompt` and running...

```
cd /D "%SystemRoot%"
dir %SystemDrive%\
dir %SystemDrive%
```

The second command (e.g. `dir C:\`) will show the contents of the root directory of the system drive, whereas the last command (e.g. `dir C:`) will display the contents of the current directory on the system drive, which is the system directory (e.g. `C:\Windows`).  That's because it is a *relative* path but for a specific drive.  From [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#fully-qualified-vs-relative-paths)...

> If a file name begins with only a disk designator but not the backslash after the colon, it is interpreted as a relative path to the current directory on the drive with the specified letter. Note that the current directory may or may not be the root directory depending on what it was set to during the most recent "change directory" operation on that disk. Examples of this format are as follows:
>
> - "C:tmp.txt" refers to a file named "tmp.txt" in the current directory on drive C.
> - "C:tempdir\tmp.txt" refers to a file in a subdirectory to the current directory on drive C.

Assuming when you start `C:\Users\Name\Desktop\App.exe` it has a working directory of `C:\Users\Name\Desktop\`, by passing `"C:"` to the `FileSystemWatcher` it ends up just watching the `C:\Users\Name\Desktop\` directory, not the entire volume like you want.  I tested your code in a quick .NET Core application and confirmed that when passing `"C:"` only changes made in the current (application) directory are reported, whereas when passing `@"C:\"` it does correctly monitor the entire volume.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this before. Like you I was able to get some directories to work fine but specifying an entire drive never really worked properly until I allowed "Auditing Permissions" on all folders for the entire drive.

Depending on you operating system and version you are running on the directions will differ but here is for Windows 10 [Apply a basic audit policy on a file or folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/apply-a-basic-audit-policy-on-a-file-or-folder). Be aware it can take a bit to apply the changes for an entire drive.

Hope that helps.

Happy coding!!!